# Django import export: skip_unchanged = True doesn't skip older records and also imports unchanged values

Tags: python, django

```
@admin.register(Hospital)
class HospitalAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    pass

class HospitalResource(resources.ModelResource):
    model = Hospital
    skip_unchanged = True
    report_skipped = False
```

I have also tried using other available mixins, but somehow cannot get this working. I want unchanged records/values to be skipped during the import.

Answer (score 1):

You need to let your HospitalAdmin class know which resource it'll be using, as well as add a `Meta` tag. Add `resource_class = HospitalResource` to your HospitalAdmin class, and wrap your HospitalResource in a Hospital `Meta` class and it should work as expected.

```
@admin.register(Hospital)
class HospitalAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = HospitalResource
    pass

class HospitalResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Hospital
        skip_unchanged = True
        report_skipped = False
```